# ¿Como resolver un fragment que es llamado desde un activity y se esta superpuesto o se queda uno encima del otro?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un `activity` que me muestra una lista de coordenadas, el cual también contiene un botón flotante para mostrar o llamar un registro nuevo que esta creado con un `fragment`, el detalle que al llamar ese `fragment` desde el `activity` al momento de compilar mi app se muestra empalmadas o superpuestas tanto como las lista y el registro, alguien me podría orientar como poder resolver ese detalle.

**Activity.java**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista__ubicacion_mex);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Puntos de evacuación Edomex");

    BtnFlotante1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh_EvacuaEdomex);
    BtnFlotante2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_nuevoRegistroPuntos);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.id_listView_EvacuaEdomex);
    evacuacionEddomexAdapter = new AdapterEvacuacionEdomex(this,evacuacionEdoMexArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(evacuacionEddomexAdapter);

    BtnFlotante1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Lista_EvacuacionEdomex.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    BtnFlotante2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerRegisEvacua,
                    new RegistroPuntoEvacuacionEdomex()).commit();
        }
    });
  }
```

**Archivo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".AdminOperacionesAlbergues.CategoriaPEMexico.Lista_EvacuacionEdomex">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/id_listView_EvacuaEdomex"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_refresh_EvacuaEdomex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/refresh_list_ropa"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_nuevoRegistroPuntos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mas"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>


  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerRegisEvacua"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </FrameLayout>

  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Captura**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones tu ListView dentro del FrameLayout? Como duda aparte, ¿QUieres que el Fragment figure debajo del contenido de tu actividad, o que lo de tu actividad desaparezca y figure solo el fragment?

Comment: Que la actividad desaparezca y lo reemplace el fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dejo aquí una solución que no es de lo más óptima pero se adapta a lo que necesitas. Lo primero que puedes hacer es añadir un **ID** a tus `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
```

Y luego declararlos en el `onCreate`:

```
    LinearLayout ll1 = findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    LinearLayout ll2 = findViewById(R.id.ll2);
```

Lo segundo es utilizar la propiedad `setVibility` y asignarle el valor `GONE` luego de presionado el botón con el cuál cargarías el `Fragment`:

```
    fab2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        ll1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ll2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerRegisEvacua,
                new RegistroPuntoEvacuacionEdomex()).commit();
    });
```

Con esto, mostraríamos el `Fragment` y ocultaríamos el `ListView`. Paso a explicar, al utilizar la propiedad `GONE` todo lo que tengamos **"desaparecerá"** sin ocupar espacio en nuestro `Layout`. Distinto es con `INVISIBLE`, ya que esta si bien oculta los elementos, estos siguen ocupando el espacio en el `Layout`. Espero que te sirva la respuesta :) Dejo un **GIF** demostrativo de mi solución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me sirvió tu respuesta, ya que para lo que lo necesito esta bien, gracias.